# Kube-apiserver Unable to authenticate the requests, All workers NotReady Status

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubectl

**All of the workers status are NotReady.**

**Kubelet on worker node shows below problem.**
[Kubelet stopped posting node status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULk3f.png)

**Inspecting one of the workers kubelet shows below.**

[systemctl status kubelet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOvkA.jpg)

**Seems to be kubelet cannot access kube-apiserver**

```
$ curl -k https://192.168.1.50:8443/healthz 
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.50 port 8443 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

**Both kube-apiserver log are as below
[Pod1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsMfn.jpg)
[Pod2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCYGB.jpg)**

Seems like cert got problem, we did a kubeadm certs renew all few days earlier when facing a X509: Certificate Has Expired Or Is Not Yet Valid error, our cluster is up for over a year and the certs expired, so we renewed it. Not sure is it related, or we configured it wrong.

**[Edited] Seems like etcd and kube-apiserver is restarting alot**

**kubectl get pods -n kube-system output
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1KRY.jpg)**

**Other informations**

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy

Package Info - kubernetes v1.22.12 - keepalived v2.2.4 - haproxy v
Containerd v1.5.9-0
Kubernetes Services Version
Calico v3.21
Kubeflow v1.6